# rosjava and pr2 tutorial

Tags: pr2, ros-groovy, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone have a decent tutorial for using rosjava and a PR2?  Even a simple tutorial would be greatly beneficial.

Anything with the PR2, actionlib, rosjava groovy would be a great help.  I can't find anything.

Thanks,
James

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58637/rosjava-and-pr2-tutorial/) by [jforkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/4213/jforkey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2013-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you've covered all the ROSJAVA documentation, you'll find that ROSJava_core development separate from the roscpp development cycles such as Groovy and Fuerte. The integration between a PR2 (or any system) and ROSJAVA is through the message interface. On thing that may restrict you is the lack of a [action interface](http://answers.ros.org/question/37198/rosjava-actionlib/) in ROSJAVA. Your solution in that case is to write a node implementing the interface in [another language as a proxy](http://answers.ros.org/question/40613/actionclient-in-rosjava/).

Other than that it would be a matter of determining the interface you are after and implementing it using the publishers, subscribers,servers and clients in rosjava_core. All the message types are available in rosjava_core.

**EDIT**

I dont have a tutorial, but I used [rosjava to publish](http://answers.ros.org/question/58356/ompl_planninggetmotionplan-returns-non-valid-trajectories/) GetMotionPlan messages to the ompl_planning node. The key to using these complex message types is creating a variable from the interface using `node.getTopicMessageFactory().newFromType(TYPE)` as in the example:

```
trajectory_msgs.JointTrajectoryPoint point1= node.getTopicMessageFactory().newFromType(JointTrajectoryPoint._TYPE);
```

This allows complex messages, particularly those that contain Java List<> types to be filled and then placed in the message field using one of the message interface's set commands.

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jforkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/4213/jforkey/) on 2013-03-21**:
Other than that it would be a matter of determining the interface you are after and implementing it using the publishers, subscribers,servers and clients in rosjava_core. All the message types are available in rosjava_core.

Can you point to a tutorial that does this for any single interface?

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2013-03-22**:
see edit above

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are [general support guidelines](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support).

Each important component has its wiki page with everything appertaining:

- [rosjava](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava_core),
  docs etc. linked there.
- [PR2](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/PR2),
  tutorials etc. linked there.
- [actionlib](http://www.ros.org/wiki/actionlib),
  tutorials linked there.

To get an idea how to glue components read the [introduction](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Introduction).

To find code [browse the ros](http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php).

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jforkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/4213/jforkey/) on 2013-03-21**:
A) The rosjava link simply references another external link, which I have read entirely multiple times.
B) The PR2 link contains links for other versions of ROS, not groovy, or anything about rosjava.
C) The actionlib link is for ROS (C++), not rosjava.

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-03-21**:
So I'm glad your question wasn't as blunt as it seems to me due to those aspects missing. :)